# Invalid Token JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, postman

I've got a problem, when I'm trying to use the get method in the "localhost:3300/api/user/all" (or any other) it shows me an error in Postman ""error": "Invalid token"". I'm putting my token in the Authorization header using format "Bearer ". I'm clueless what can cause it.

My user.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/user");
const {
  verifyToken,
  verifyTokenAndAdmin,
} = require("../routes/verifyToken");

router.get("/:id", verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
    }
    res.json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});

router.get("/", verifyTokenAndAdmin, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find({});
    res.json(users);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});
router.put("/:id", verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
    }
    user.firstName = req.body.firstName;
    user.lastName = req.body.lastName;
    user.address = req.body.address;
    user.phone = req.body.phone;
    user.dateOfBirth = req.body.dateOfBirth;

    const updatedUser = await user.save();
    res.json(updatedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});

router.delete("/:id", verifyTokenAndAdmin, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
    }

    await user.remove();
    res.json({ message: "User deleted successfully" });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

My verifyToken.js

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");



const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const authtoken = req.header("Authorization");
  const token = authtoken.split(" ")[1];

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "No token, authorization denied" });
  }

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(token)
    res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid token" });
  }
};
const verifyTokenAndAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
  verifyToken(req, res, () => {
    // Check if the user is an admin
    if (!req.user.isAdmin) {
      return res.status(403).json({ error: "Admin access required" });
    }
    next();
  });
};

const verifyTokenAndAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  verifyToken(req, res, () => {

    next();
  });
};

module.exports = {
  verifyToken,
  verifyTokenAndAdmin,
  verifyTokenAndAuth,
};
```

[image: And Postman screenshot]

Comment: Why don't you log the actual error message after `catch (err)`  instead of just returning a generic "Invalid token"?

Comment: just change your header `req.header("Authorization");` to `req.header("bearer");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you inspect the server logs?

It looks like you should change `verifyToken` in verifyToken.js to log the error in the catch block instead of the token. That should get you closer to debugging.

Most likely the error is thrown in this line:

```
const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
```

Either the verification fails or `JWT_SECRET` is invalid.

Change the lines below to see the error:

```
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err) // <- err instead of token
    res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid token" });
  }
```